# Cosmos Hive error entering and using map reduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, fiware, fiware-cosmos

I've a couple of problems executing Hive on cosmos fiware lab instance.

First, after log into the machine, I enter in Hive command line and I get the following error (I saw other questions related to this, but I couldn't find a solution):

```
$ hive
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate class [org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HiveEventCounter].
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load shims in class org.apache.hadoop.log.metrics.EventCounter
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.createShim(ShimLoader.java:123)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.loadShims(ShimLoader.java:115)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.getEventCounter(ShimLoader.java:98)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HiveEventCounter.<init>(HiveEventCounter.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:310)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByClassName(OptionConverter.java:330)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByKey(OptionConverter.java:121)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:664)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:647)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:544)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:440)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:476)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:354)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.common.LogUtils.initHiveLog4jDefault(LogUtils.java:127)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.common.LogUtils.initHiveLog4jCommon(LogUtils.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.common.LogUtils.initHiveLog4j(LogUtils.java:58)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:641)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:625)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.log.metrics.EventCounter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:171)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.createShim(ShimLoader.java:120)
    ... 27 more
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "EventCounter".

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/local/apache-hive-0.13.0-bin/lib/hive-common-0.13.0.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
```

However, I'm able to run a query like SELECT * FROM table;

On the other hand, if I try to run other query more specific like display only a column field, a map reduce job starts to run and it results in the following error:

```
hive> SELECT table.column FROM table;
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
Starting Job = job_201507101501_40071, Tracking URL = http://cosmosmaster-gi:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201507101501_40071
Kill Command = /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_201507101501_40071
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers: 0
2016-01-29 12:49:45,518 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2016-01-29 12:50:08,642 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%
Ended Job = job_201507101501_40071 with errors
Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
Job Tracking URL: http://cosmosmaster-gi:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201507101501_40071
Examining task ID: task_201507101501_40071_m_000002 (and more) from job job_201507101501_40071

Task with the most failures(4): 
-----
Task ID:
  task_201507101501_40071_m_000000

URL:
  http://cosmosmaster-gi:50030/taskdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201507101501_40071&tipid=task_201507101501_40071_m_000000
-----
Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:386)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:324)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:266)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1278)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:260)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.jav

FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Job 0: Map: 1   HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
```

Any help or suggestion is welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The first error is not relevant and does not affect Hive querying, as you have seen.

Regarding the second error, most probably it is because the stored data in HDFS is in Json format (most probably stored by the Cygnus tool) and a Json SerializerDeserializer (serde) must be set. You can do this by executoing the following sentence before doing the `select column from table`:

```
$ add jar /usr/local/apache-hive-0.13.0-bin/lib/json-serde-1.3.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar;
$ select column from table;
```